# What are all the special characters in Uri?

Tags: c#, encoding, uri, special-characters

I have below code:

```
string myString = "test://mytest/v1.0~admin#1~password";
var myUri = new Uri(myString);
```

I find the part after `#` are not in `myUri.LocalPath`.

I tried to replace hash (`#`) with `'` or `&`, there is no problem. Where I can know all the special characters like `#` will cause the same issue in Uri?

Comment: The part after # isn't *supposed* to be part of `LocalPath`... the `#` character delimits the fragment part of the URI.

Comment: I find below code could keep the # in uri : myString = myString.Replace("#", Uri.HexEscape('#'));  I find it here:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1c72950-e07e-4935-bd70-7b5d68da6437/uri-class-not-works-for-ftpwebrequest-if-having-special-characters-in-uri-path-help?forum=netfxbcl Is there a common method in C# will do this conversion for me for the whole string? In case there are more special characters, not just "#"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hash "#" is available to the client only, and is not sent to the server. It can be accessed from JS for client-side navigation (i.e. single-page apps). The ampersand is used as a delimiter for values passed to a GET request after the question mark. For example: http://example.com/controller/action?a=1&b=2&c=3#client-only passes the integer values in a, b and c to the server, where they will be either parsed into method parameters. The section after the '#' is ignored by the server.